# Positioning Text Under Images - HTML Email

Tags: html, css, image, email

I'm trying to position text and a button underneath my image links in a HTML email template, below is an attached photo for reference of what I want to do:

[image]

So far, I have this code to display my images:

```
<br />
<a href="*LINK*"><img src="*IMAGE*" style="max-width:298px;" id="bodyImage2" mc:label="body_image2" mc:edit="body_image2" mc:allowtext /></a>
<a href="*LINK*"><img src="*IMAGE*" style="max-width:298px;" id="bodyImage3" mc:label="body_image3" mc:edit="body_image3" mc:allowtext /></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The above card is part of a table labelled as "bodyContent"".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below snippet. It might help you.

```html
<table  border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=700 style="margin: 0 auto;background-color:#FFF6F5;">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" style="text-align: center;">
      <img src="http://www.demilked.com/magazine/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/surreal-photoshop-images-shelter-animals-sarolta-ban-thumb290.jpg" />
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, w</p>
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </td>
    <td width="50%" style="text-align: center;">
      <img src="http://www.onesmallseed.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/HOMEPAGE.jpg" />
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, w</p>
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With HTML email, unfortunately you're talking tables, tables and more tables. Back to the future, right? Support for styles and specifically style elements critical to layout varies widely among email clients. Ditto support for forms, so make sure your "buttons" are either text elements or images inside anchor tags. Try something like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>image1</td><td>image2</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" valign="top">blurb1</td><td align="center"  valign="top">blurb2</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" valign="top">button code1</td><td align="center" valign="top">button code2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Html emails, a basic principle is that each element needs to be separated into its own row/cells of a table. Once this is done, use the inline css style attribute on a `td` to control padding, font style, etc of your content.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="...">
            <img .../>
        </td>
        <td style="...">
            <img .../>
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="...">
            <p>...</p>
        </td>
        <td style="...">
            <p>...</p>
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="...">
            <button .../>
        </td>
        <td style="...">
            <button .../>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```